# Combine cells having similar values in a row

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a data frame like below.

```
   New_ment1_1   New_ment1_2     New_ment1_3            New_ment1_4
 1 application     android           ios                     NA
 2 donald trump    agreement      climate               united states
 3 donald trump    agreement       paris                united states
 4 donald trump    agreement    united states                NA
 5 donald trump     climate      emission               united states
 6 donald trump   entertainer      host                  president
 7 hen             chicken       mustard                    wimp
 8 husband          pamela      private lives                NA
 9 pan             chicken         hen                      wimp
10 sex            associate        pamela                   partner
11 united kingdom  chicken         hen                      wimp
12 united states  agreement       paris                     NA
```

And I want the resultant as a data frame with rows like below

For example, 
Row1 should be as such since it doesn't have any similar rows.

if you see rows 2,3,4,5 and 12. They should be combined in a same row like

```
united states  donald trump  paris  climate  agreement  emission
```

And rows 7,9 and 11 should be combined as

```
united  kingdom  chicken  hen  wimp  mustard
```

It can be in any order.

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by "similar". Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: similar as in, in a row of 4 words, if two same words are there in two rows, I want to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data frame `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

Convert that to a character matrix `m`. Let us say that two rows are similar if they have more than one element in common and define `is_similar` to take two row indexes and return TRUE or FALSE accordingly.  Then apply that to every pair of rows using `outer`.  Interpret that as the adjacency matrix of a graph and calculate the connected compnents splitting `DF` into a list `L` each of whose elements is a data frame of the rows from `DF` that constitute that connected component..  Finally rework `L` into a character matrix.

```
library(igraph)

m <- as.matrix(DF)
n <- nrow(m)
is_similar <- function(i, j) length(intersect(na.omit(m[i, ]), na.omit(m[j, ]))) > 1
smat <- outer(1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(is_similar))

adj <- graph.adjacency(smat)
cl <- components(adj)$membership

str(split(1:n, cl))
## List of 6
##  $ 1: int 1
##  $ 2: int [1:5] 2 3 4 5 12
##  $ 3: int 6
##  $ 4: int [1:3] 7 9 11
##  $ 5: int 8
##  $ 6: int 10

spl <- split(DF, cl)
L <- lapply(spl, function(x) na.omit(unique(unlist(x))))
t(do.call("cbind", lapply(L, ts)))
```

giving:

```
  [,1]           [,2]            [,3]             [,4]        [,5]      [,6]      
1 "application"  "android"       "ios"            NA          NA        NA        
2 "donald_trump" "united_states" "agreement"      "climate"   "paris"   "emission"
3 "donald_trump" "entertainer"   "host"           "president" NA        NA        
4 "hen"          "pan"           "united_kingdom" "chicken"   "mustard" "wimp"    
5 "husband"      "pamela"        "private_lives"  NA          NA        NA        
6 "sex"          "associate"     "pamela"         "partner"   NA        NA
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
 New_ment1_1   New_ment1_2     New_ment1_3            New_ment1_4
 1 application     android           ios                     NA
 2 donald_trump    agreement      climate               united_states
 3 donald_trump    agreement       paris                united_states
 4 donald_trump    agreement    united_states                NA
 5 donald_trump     climate      emission               united_states
 6 donald_trump   entertainer      host                  president
 7 hen             chicken       mustard                    wimp
 8 husband          pamela      private_lives                NA
 9 pan             chicken         hen                      wimp
10 sex            associate        pamela                   partner
11 united_kingdom  chicken         hen                      wimp
12 united_states  agreement       paris                     NA"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

**Update:** Fixed similarity definition.